# Redirect nonsubdomain to www ignoring subdomains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

First of all I will say that I search for solution but I didn't found working answer :(

I have 1 project in 1 root folder with multiple subdomains (language versions):

> en.sitedomain.com
>
> de.sitedomain.com
>
> fr.sitedomain.com

And I have a `www.sitedomain.com` version.

I need to make a redirect when someone goes to sitedomain.com (without any subdomain) to be redirected to www.sitedomain.com

I tried with something as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I got wrong redirects

```
subdomain.com ==>> www.subdomain.com  CORRECT
www.subdomain.com ==>> www.subdomain.com  CORRECT 
en.subdomain.com ==>> www.en.subdomain.com  WRONG !!!
de.subdomain.com ==>> www.de.subdomain.com  WRONG !!!
```

Can anyone help me please :)

Comment: So why don’t you simply check whether the HOST is _exactly_ `sitedomain.com` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you only have to do is this: verify if `HTTP_HOST` is equals to `sitedomain.com`.
If it is then redirect to `www.sitedomain.com`.

Try the following (i've omitted `https` part)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitedomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```